# numpy: arange include endpoint

Tags: python, numpy

I need to transfer some Matlab code into P. I got stuck at a `numpy.arange` I use to set points continuously on the arc of circle with a given angle (in radians).

I got this far (example for points on x-axis):

```
def sensor_data_arc_x():
    theta = np.arange(0, angle/2, 2*np.pi/360)
    return np.multiply(radius, np.cos(np.transpose(theta)))
```

I know `numpy.arange` does not include the endpoint, although the Matlab equivalent does; the array is always one element short, which is messing up my further computations.

Is there an way to include the endpoint?

Comment: `np.linspace` gives you more control over end points.  It's usually better when working with floats.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend that you work through a tutorial on `for` loops -- the information you need is there, as well as other hints on using controlled iteration.  To solve your immediate need, simply increase your upper bound by one loop increment:

```
inc = 2*np.pi/360
theta = np.arange(0, angle/2 + inc, inc)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if angle/4 < inc < angle/2